# using word "Responsive" correctly?

Tags: meaning, verbs, syntactic-analysis

I wrote this sentence for my report, but I am not fully comfortable in using "responsive". Can any one check and point out the mistakes?
**Various constraints relating RGB cameras were found to be responsive to color and illumination changes, surrounding clutters and disorders.**

Comment: Can you further explain what you're trying to say? "responsive" seems appropriate. What do you mean by, "surrounding clutters and disorders"?

Comment: @LittleEva: Actually I want to know that "responsive" fits correctly in the sentence? and color and illumination changes, surrounding clutters and disorders are disadvantages of RGB cameras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will be comfortable using [responsive](https://www.google.com/search?q=responsive&oq=responsive&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.619549j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8); (adjective):

1.
reacting quickly and positively.
"a flexible service that is responsive to changing social and economic patterns."

Synonyms:   quick to react to, reactive to, receptive to, open to suggestions about, amenable to, flexible to, sensitive to, sympathetic to.

Aware of,
"several consumers said the company hadn't been responsive to their needs."

Responding readily and with interest or enthusiasm.
"our most enthusiastic and responsive students.
"

Denoting or relating to a website whose page design changes automatically according to the size of the screen on which it is viewed.
"a responsive site that would work on PCs and tablets equally well."

2.
answering.
"I'm distracted by a nibble on my line: I jig it several times, but there is no responsive tug."

However, the sentence could be rewritten "various constraints relating to RGB cameras were found to be responsive to color and illumination changes in the  surroundings."

Comment: I cannot see how "constraints" could be responsive.  Do you mean that depending on those factors you mentioned, the constraints would vary?   It seems as though perhaps those factors contitute restraints (or act as limitations) on the camera's performance.

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock - I took it OP to mean the constraints (or, limitations) of RGB cameras were diminished by "color and illumination changes," - I asked OP about the meaning of "surrounding clutters and disorders" but OP was not forthcoming, stating that he was only concerned with the usage of "responsive", at that point I gave up.

Comment: Maybe his responsiveness was constrained to zero.